# Unable to Add ArcGIS Server to ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server

I am using ArcMap 10.3.1 and trying to make a connection with federated ArcGIS Server 10.6.1.

I am Getting this error message:

> We were unable to connect to: `http://arcgisserver:6443/arcgis`. Error :
> Bad syntax in request. (status code 400)

[image]

What could the problem be?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve error messages we ask that you show us them in full using text rather than a picture so that they can be searched and also read easily on all devices.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **" "** button that enables you to format any highlighted text nicely.

Comment: Given that you are trying to connect three major releases into the future, you should start by reviewing the compatibility documentation, to see if this is possible.

Comment: according to the official documentation of esri, it is possible to connect to arcgis server 10.6.1 with a previous version of arcgis desktop

Answer (score 2):

From the ArcGIS manual [About Connecting to ArcGIS Server in ArcGIS for Desktop](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/10.6/administer/windows/about-connecting-to-arcgis-server-in-arcgis-for-desktop.htm):

> **Specifying the server URL**
>   Specifying the server URL When you connect, you'll be asked to type
>   the URL to your ArcGIS Server site. For user connections, you'll often
>   include the name of the ArcGIS Web Adaptor in your URL. This will look
>   like http://webadaptorhost.domain.com/webadaptorname/services.
>
> For publisher and administrative connections, access through the web
>   adaptor is blocked by most organizations. Instead, you need to use the
>   administrative URL of the server, which takes the format
>   http://gisserver.domain.com:6080/arcgis.
>
> Some sites may require an HTTPS connection through port 6443. Check
>   with your server administrator if you are unsure of the appropriate
>   URL to use.
>
> **If you receive an error when connecting, one of more of the following
>   may be the cause:**
>
> - You typed an incorrect name or password.
> - You did not use your server’s expected protocol of HTTP or HTTPS.
> - You did not include the fully qualified domain name of the server (which is required in scenarios where the server is federated with
>     Portal for ArcGIS).

It is worth also to read the [Compatibility of ArcGIS for server with earlier versions](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/10.6/get-started/windows/compatibility-of-arcgis-for-server-with-earlier-versions.htm)

> **Can I view and use my 10.6.1 services within an earlier version of
>   ArcGIS Desktop?**
>
> You can add 10.6.1 services to earlier versions of ArcGIS Desktop and
>   use them in the same way that you used them in the past, including as
>   a layer in ArcMap. However, if your ArcGIS Server10.6.1 site is
>   federated with Portal for ArcGIS and the portal is configured with
>   Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML), you must at least use
>   ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.
>
> If your 10.6.1 ArcGIS Server site is federated with Portal for ArcGIS
>   and you are connecting from a pre-10.2 version of ArcGIS Desktop, you
>   must access your services through ArcMap using Add Data > Add Data
>   from Portal for ArcGIS. You cannot connect to the server by clicking
>   Add ArcGIS Server.

Comment: i am using 10.3.1 version of ArcGIS Desktop, the article talks about a version < 12.1

Comment: Every ArcGIS for Desktop in earlier versions can connect to the 10.6.1 ArcGIS Server if they are not configured by Portal for ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Can the problem be that you are using http to access a port that requires https?

https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/install/windows/ports-used-by-arcgis-server.htm

Normally it should default to 6443 when you use https. Do you get the same error if you try https://arcgisserver/arcgis?

Comment: I tried both, and still geting the error

Comment: Can you e.g. access the REST endpoint at https://10.134.135.89/arcgis/rest/ with a browser?

Comment: Yes i do using the port 6443

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string starts with HTTP, but port 6443 works just for HTTPS. For HTTP use port 6080.